# Ruby - Several problems while displaying files

Tags: ruby, file, io, menu

G'day,

I am writing a little tool. But discovered several problems in the same code chunk. So because of not knowing what to do, I ask here now.

the Code:

```ruby
def deleteExistingDatabase
  puts <<-DELETEDATABASE
    ####################################################
    #|                                                |#
    #|  Delete a existing Database                    |#
    #|  ------------------                            |#
    #|                                                |#
    #|  Which one do you want to delete?              |#
    #|  ------                                        |#
  DELETEDATABASE
  files = 0
  Dir.foreach("./database/") do |entry|
    files += 1
    puts  "    #|   #{files}. #{entry}                                     |#"
  end

end
```

and this is the result:

```bash
    ####################################################
    #|                                                |#
    #|  Delete a existing Database                    |#
    #|  ------------------                            |#
    #|                                                |#
    #|  Which one do you want to delete?              |#
    #|  ------                                        |#
    #|   1. aFileWithAVeryLongNameIsInHere.db                                     |#
    #|   2. middlelenghts.db                                     |#
    #|   3. ..                                     |#
    #|   4. short.db                                     |#
    #|   5. .                                     |#
```

The most obvious question is: Is it possible to write content in the layout without destroying it? I mean, if a filename is too long, its normal that the design breaks. But even if it would fit perfectly the design is breaking.

next question: There are just 3 files in the directory. But I got 5 results.. why? What are these dots and how can I get rid of them?

last question: if I ask the user which file he wants to delete. how can I assure to pick the right one, because 1-3 is just generated by file += 1 so I cannot know what is the users 1 or 2.

I hope you guys know how to help me, because I am totaly lost.
Thanks in advance, VB

Comment: 1) [`String#ljust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-ljust) 2 and 3) the extra 2 are `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory) as show in `Dir#foreach` maybe use `Dir.glob('./database/*)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The most obvious question is: Is it possible to write content in the layout without destroying it? I mean, if a filename is too long, it's normal that the design breaks. But even if it would fit perfectly the design is breaking.

The code does exactly what you wrote. `puts` command prints spaces, hashbang, vertical line, then spaces, filename and given number of spaces again. To fix its result you need to adjust the length of filename to some limit, by adding spaces to the end. You could use [ljust](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-ljust) method for this purpose:

```
puts  "    #|   #{files}. #{entry.to_s.ljust(35)} |#"
```

With this code the filename will be padded with spaces to the length of 35 chars.

> next question: There are just 3 files in the directory. But I got 5 results.. why? What are these dots and how can I get rid of them?

These are special hidden files. `.` is for the directory itself, `..` is for its parent directory. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory) for more details. You could skip them like this, for example:

```
Dir.entries("./database/").select { |entry| !%w[. ..].include?(entry) }.each do |entry|
  ...
```

The other option is to use [children](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Dir.html#method-c-children) method:

```
Dir.children("./database/").each do |entry|
  ...
```

> last question: if I ask the user which file he wants to delete. how can I assure to pick the right one, because 1-3 is just generated by file += 1 so I cannot know what is the users 1 or 2.

Hm. I don't think it's a good idea actually. In multiprocess systems another process could delete the file in the directory after you printed its content but before the user makes a selection. As a result, an incorrect file is selected.

Comment: For the last question you could save all file names in an array (i.e. `files = Dir["./database/*.*"]`) and then find the selected file name within that array.

Comment: You guys are awesome! I made It working nice with your suggestions! Thank you very much.